# Direct page to other page

Tags: html, redirect

I am using HTML and would like to know why when I enter

```
<a class="button flip" href="index2.html">List View</a>
```

it tries to find the original_page_url#index2.html

thanks

Charlene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that code that you've put it shouldn't be doing that which means something else on your page is doing that. Javascript is the most likely culprit since it can easily change where your link actually goes. There may be other ways this could happen but I'd look at your javascript.

If you post a full page repro of the problem that we can use to understand the problem better that would help a lot. Preferably cutting out all the superfluous stuff on your page so its not too big. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Without further information from you, the only three things I can think of that would cause that are:

1) Your href in your question is different than your actual source, and there is a # sign before the `index2.html` in the `a` link. However, I'll assume you gave the correct href code above, in which case...

2) Some javascript on the page is automatically making that link act as an internal page link and adding the # itself. Make sure you don't have any javascript on the page that might be doing that.

3) The server has a rewrite rule that affects your links and appends them with the # sign. That would be rather odd, however.